# Boost Filesystem -- enumerating devices?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

All,

I am trying to write a cross platform (hence: boost) method/function that will enumerate all of the storage devices on a system.  From what I have found, the Boost docs mention multiple root file systems, but does not elaborate on how to handle them.  I assume that a Windows machine with a hard disk, CD/DVD drive, a USB drive, etc, would be considered a 'multiple root system' -- correct?  If not, what is the root?

I assume that in Linux, there is a single root (e.g., /dev), but I'm not sure how to do it for a multi-root system (e.g., Window) using Boost.  Is there a Boost method to enumerate devices?

Help?

Thank you very much,

:bp:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is a **single-root** system, rooted at `\`, but they're not "file" systems -- they're other kinds of objects. (Devices, drivers, files, directories, object types, events, mutants, event pairs, window stations, security tokens, semaphores, timers, sessions, memory sections, ...)

(See [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657).)

I don't think there's any Boost method for enumerating these, since people frown at you if you use the native NT API. (The Win32 subsystem doesn't expose these; it only exposes the `\??\` directory.) Nevertheless, you can use functions like [`NtOpenDirectoryObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470234.aspx) to enumerate these.